# Jquery call function in custom plugin

Tags: jquery, plugins

I want to call search function inside init function. But I got this error:  element.search is not a function. Also there is a error: plugin.on is not a function. Is there is a way to do it correctly?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.fn.id_card = function() {
    var element = this; 
    return {
        search: function () {
            var fin_code = $("#input_fin");
            fin_code.removeClass("form-control-danger");
            if(fin_code.val().length != 7) {
                fin_code.addClass("form-control-danger");
                return false;
            }

            var fin_code_value = fin_code.val();
            element.trigger('search_complete', {"abcdef": "ghijkl"});
        },      
        init: function(customer_data = {}) {
            const FIN = customer_data.FIN ? customer_data.FIN : "";
            var html="";
            html += "<div class=\"id_card\" id=\"id_card_front\">";
            html += "   <input type=\"text\" name=\"number\" maxlength=\"7\" class=\"form-control input_fin\" placeholder=\"FIN\" autocomplete=\"off\" value=\"" + FIN + "\" id=\"input_fin\">";
            html += "   <button type=\"button\" id=\"fin-btn-search\" class=\"btn btn-primary fin-btn fin-btn-search\">Axtar<\/button>";
            html += "<\/div>";
            element.html(html);

            $("#fin-btn-search").click(function() {
                element.search();
            });

        }
    }
};
</script>

<div class="row container-fluid">
    <div class="col-sm-12" id="id_card_widget"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var plugin = $( "#id_card_widget" ).id_card();
    var data = {"FIN": "1R30N3R"};  // default value eger varsa, otururuk javascript-e. Yoxdursa bos da oture bilerik, oturmeye de bilerik
    plugin.init(data);

    plugin.on('search_complete', function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        return response;
    });

</script>
```